# External Data Source for Microsoft CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

The question itself is very tricky. But I'll try to break it down into pieces.

Let's say I have external datasources each of them providing my data model. Either a webservice, or database. What matters is that my Entities are defined and exists in separated systems than the Dynamics builtin database.

What I want to do is to use the capabilities of CRM, to handle Business Entities (Provided from the external source), aspects such as security, and UI. Are well managed inside the CRM. So I want to build my system, using this tool, but I want to be able to store and keep the data in my own sources.

In other words, is there a way in CRM (Through the webServices I believe), in which I can provide the entity, and have it managed later inside the CRM.

thanks in advance... I really hope I can find the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option you have is to synchronize the data stored inside Dynamics CRM database with your external sources.

With tools like [Scribe](http://www.scribesoft.com/) from Scribesoft, this scenario is manageable.

Comment: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/abf61d02-379c-49eb-a155-7e8df5c87aaf

Answer (score 0):

About 50% of the functionality of MS CRM is implemented via rather convoluted SQL views/queries/stored functions etc. It is much more then a simple "table per entity type" data store. There is no way to keep live data "somewhere else", so you are stuck with import/export (as recommended in the previous answer).